# Product of cells with changing row number

Tags: excel

I'd like to get the product of the last three cells in the certain column. The row numbers will change as the data increases. For example,

```
ColA
2
4
1
6
5
```

The product of the last three cells in ColA will be 30 (1*6*5).

```
ColA
2
4
1
6
5
7
3
```

Now the product of the last three cells in ColA becomes 105(5*7*3).

Is there a function in Excel (not =Product) that will do the calculation above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=PRODUCT(INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,A:A)-2):INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,A:A)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Scott. Could you tell me what does 1E+99 mean?

Comment: The MATCH(1E+99,A:A) finds the last cell in which there is a number and returns that row number to the INDEX() Formula.  It looks for an impossible high number so by the nature of the MATCH it will find the last cell where it is larger but smaller than the next, so it finds the last instead.

Comment: How to type in 1E+99? Please don't laugh at my naive question XD.

Comment: literally type `1E+99` or I type `1e99` Excel will understand what is meant.  it would equal 1 with 99 0s after it.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!